# There is a StoreRequest there is a pair of field and non-image loading, how can I ignore these conditions when editing?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

There is a StoreRequest there is a pair of field and non-image loading, how can I ignore these conditions when editing?

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|unique',
            'image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png'
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Look at "sometimes" rule : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: not suitable for loading images, plus the title field always gets into an array